# How I can count bounding boxes in each frame?

Tags: python, opencv, count

I need to know how I can count for bounding boxes in each frame?

I need to know the total bounding boxes, so I know when I need to add new object to be tracking, when `total bounding boxes in current frame > total bounding boxes in previous frame`

I already try with store centroid coordinate (cx,cy) into a list:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

bgsMOG    = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(50,3,0.8)
cap       = cv2.VideoCapture("d:\\MOV_5702.avi")
a         = []


if cap:
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret:
            fgmask              = bgsMOG.apply(frame, None, 0.99)
            contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            cv2.drawContours(frame,contours,-1,(0,255,0),cv2.cv.CV_FILLED,32)
            try: hierarchy = hierarchy[0]
            except: hierarchy = []
            for contour, hier in zip(contours, hierarchy):
                (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                
                if w > 20 and h > 20:
                    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (180,0,0), 1)
                    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
                       
                    x1=w/2
                    y1=h/2
                    cx=x+x1
                    cy=y+y1
                    a.append([cx,cy])
                    print(len(a))
                    a=[]
                            
            cv2.imshow('BGS', fgmask)
            cv2.imshow('Ori+Bounding Box',frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(100)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But the result always 1..

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what do you mean, can you explain it?

Comment: Example images? Expected outcome?

Comment: @guneykayim it's just print the variable a, which is always 1.. For example: in frame 8, I have 2 bounding boxes, and in frame 9 I have 3 bounding boxes..

Comment: You still didn't provide any example images...

Comment: @guneykayim done, I put my images..

Comment: So, your visual output is correct but the variable is printed wrong?

Comment: Sorry @guneykayim, I already have the answer from aaron d, I'm just wrong to put the `a=[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have

```
a.append([cx,cy])
print(len(a))
a=[]
```

Because this runs in a loop, `a` is always going to be reset to an empty list after one item has been added (so `len(a)` will always be `1`).

Try pulling the `a=[]` outside of the `for` loop so that it happens only once per frame, rather than once per contour, and it should give a better indication of the number of bounding boxes in each frame.